# Create fluid layout like bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to HTML/CSS, so I'm probably butchering this.   I'm using bootstrap, but first day using it.  I'm trying to exactly mimic the design in the picture under "Fluid layout" in this link:  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

I currently have:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            <!--Sidebar content-->              

        </div>

        <div class="span10" >

        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

My divs' are only about an inch in height though, and I want them to go the bottom of the screen like in the picture. How do I od that?

Also, if I want to add a header bar, how do I get it so everything is below that?  Apols if this is kind of vague... I'm new to all this. My worry is that I start overwriting all sort of pre-built functionality in CSS and just end up with a monster...

Thanks!

Comment: WHy are you using an old version?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but you should know that you are not using the most recent version of Bootstrap. Bootstrap 2.3 came out roughly 18 months ago, which is a very long time in the world of front-end development. 3.2 is the newest version, and has very different markup from what you're using.

Comment: DOH!  Just saw I hit the old docs view.  thanks for that.

Comment: Is this the most recent: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Oh - is it the span classes that are old now?

Comment: There are a LOT of things that are old and a lot of new things.